# GUI for inspecting Python trace module output

Tags: python, user-interface, debugging, trace

I'm pretty new to Python programing, before I used C/C++.

To get the execution flow of a program, I used callgrind (from Valgrind toolbox), and then I opened the output with kcachegrind to have a graphical view of what happen in the program.

In Python, I know there is the `trace` module, and with the `-T (--trackcall)` option we can have the list of functions call. But it's all in raw text.

Is there a graphical tool to see the functions call from the Python `trace` output?

Comment: checkout the [Python debugger](https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/) aka pdb

Comment: Using print in Python is enough.

Comment: @AvenDesta: pdb will just give the callstack at a particular point, so it won't give a global overview of the exection flow. That means it's less than with ```trace -T```. And it's also in raw text!

Comment: @Johnny: the goal is to do not modify the code!